# Aggregate, lookup and addField from nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a trouble with MongoDB query.
First, I have a "**testScriptResultCollection**" with structure below:

```
{
    testCaseId: x
    testScriptId: 1
    descripttion: aaa

}
{
    _id: 2
    testCaseId: x
    testScriptId: 2
    descripttion: bbb
}
{
    _id: 3
    testCaseId: x
    testScriptId: 3
    descripttion: ccc
}
```

and another collection is **"testCaseCollection"**:

```
{
    _id: 1
    testCaseId: x
    testScripts: [
        {
            testScriptId: 1
            name: testScript1_Name
        },
        {
            testScriptId: 2
            name: testScript2_Name
        }
        {
            testScriptId: 3
            name: testScript3_Name
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to extract an object like:

```
 [ 
        {
            testCaseId: x
            testScriptId: 1
            descripttion: aaa
            name: testScript1_Name
        },
        {
            testCaseId: x
            testScriptId: 2
            descripttion: bbb
            name: testScript2_Name
        },
        {
            testCaseId: x
            testScriptId: 3
            descripttion: ccc
            name: testScript3_Name
        },
    ]
```

I had tried a query to lookup 2 collections with **"testCaseId"** and find the **"name"** of testScriptId like that but it goes wrong

```
testScriptResultCollection.aggregate{[
    {
        $match: {testCaseId : x}
    },
    {
            $lookup:
            {
                from: "testCaseCollection"
                localField: "testCaseId",
                foreignField: "testCaseId",
                as: "combineResults"
            }
    },
    {
        $addFields : 
        {
            "name": {
                $filter: { 
                    input: "$combineResults.testScripts",
                    as: "testScriptArr",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$testScriptArr.testScriptId", $testScriptId]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

Can somebody help me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello You can try this query, but this is not the best way to do this:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rSwoGtGmwLzvIBnoBytgs-_flUblSj1agU-DGMf99U0/edit

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the answer?

Comment: Not the best way but working correctly, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

Basically you need to use [**`$mergeObjects`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) to merge both the collection objects and finally [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to shift them to the top level.

```
db.getCollection('testCaseCollection').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$testScripts" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "testScriptResultCollection",
    "localField": "testScripts.testScriptId",
    "foreignField": "testScriptId",
    "as": "newField"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$newField" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$newField", "$testScripts"] }}}
])
```

Comment: I need to get 'name' by testScriptId, so, this answer didn't resolve my problem, but anyway, thanks for your help, I also learn new things about $replaceRoot and $mergeObjects

Comment: Well here is the working example https://mongoplayground.net/p/7xMPygiSX1o.

Comment: Worked perfectly on example, but I also need to join "testScriptResultCollection" to other collections too, that means, the query should begin with db.testScriptResultCollection.aggregate([ ... ]). Could you help me to write a query from "testScriptResultCollection" join to "testCaseCollection" by "testCaseId" and get the "name" by "testScriptId"? Thank you.

Comment: Ok then please ask a new question with proper sample documents and the output. I will definitely answer